# Automation of google with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to automate google searching, and after searching click on the first website.
following are the steps:
the problem is in step three, but not clicking on the given link, and not giving any error too

1. insert values in the search box
2. click the search button
3. after searching click on the first website or any website.
   also daigram is give, its not only for yotube webite,but dynamically any website.
   the code is given if you have any solution than plz mention,

   ```
    [![attached image is here ][1]][1]from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("youtube")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3/a').click()
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, "after searching click on the first website or any website", but instead of your last line, with the xpath, I would try this to click on the first link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 driver.maximize_window()
 driver.implicitly_wait(20)
 driver.get("https://google.com")
 elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
 elem.clear()
 elem.send_keys("youtube")
 elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 time.sleep(3)
 assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.yuRUbf > a').click()
```

Or maybe more properly, since that selector returns all 10 search result links,

```
from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 driver.maximize_window()
 driver.implicitly_wait(20)
 driver.get("https://google.com")
 elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
 elem.clear()
 elem.send_keys("youtube")
 elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 time.sleep(3)
 assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
 driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.yuRUbf > a')[0].click()
```

Comment: the second solution is the perfect answer.